# Passing arguments with spaces between (bash) script

Tags: bash

I've got the following bash two scripts

a.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
./b.sh 'My Argument'
```

b.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
someApp $*
```

The someApp binary receives `$*` as 2 arguments ('My' and 'Argument') instead of 1.

I've tested several things:

- Running someApp only thru `b.sh` works as expected
- Iterate+echo the arguments in `b.sh` works as expected
- Using `$@` instead of `$*` doesn't make a difference

Comment: try `someApp "$*"` or `someApp "$@"`

Answer (score 168, accepted):

`$*`, unquoted, expands to two words. You need to quote it so that `someApp` receives a single argument.

```
someApp "$*"
```

It's possible that you want to use `$@` instead, so that `someApp` would receive two arguments if you were to call `b.sh` as

```
b.sh 'My first' 'My second'
```

With `someApp "$*"`, `someApp` would receive a single argument `My first My second`. With `someApp "$@"`, `someApp` would receive two arguments, `My first` and `My second`.

Comment: The key that is easy to miss is that "$@" needs to be quoted, it seems. $@ is not enough.

Comment: @miracle2k Correct. Unquoted, `$@` and `$*` work identically.

Comment: @Matt That is something entirely different. "$@" is special in that it quotes each argument separately. It can result in more than one argument thus. "$something" is just quotes around whatever $something expands to and will always be a single argument.

Comment: The answer only works for me if I set `IFS=$'\n'`. No idea why.