# How to save the response body from cURL in a file when executing the command in a loop in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-16.04

I've created a cURL bash script in which I want to save the response body into a file called **output.log**, but when I open the file output.log it looks like this:

[image: screenshot of the output.log file showing a line for the Header Code, a line for the execution date and HTTP/1.1 for the Response Body]

Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SECRET_KEY='helloWorld'
FILE_NAME='sma.txt'

function save_log()
{

    printf '%s\n' \
    "Header Code    : $1" \
    "Executed at    : $(date)" \
    "Response Body  : $2" \
    '==========================================================\n'  > output.log
}

while IFS= read -r line; 
    do 
        HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl -I -L -s -w "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}\\n" -H "X-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook" -H 'X-Gitlab-Token: '$SECRET_KEY --insecure $line 2>&1)
        HTTP_STATUS=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')

        save_log $HTTP_STATUS $HTTP_RESPONSE
done < $FILE_NAME
```

Can anyone help me get my desired output in my output.log?

Comment: Try to manually curl 1 URL?

Comment: Can you post an example of the content of `${FILE_NAME}`?

Comment: use double quotes for your variables : `save_log "$HTTP_STATUS" "$HTTP_RESPONSE"`

Comment: Also, you are using a loop, but in your `save_log` function you use `> output.log`. `>` will overwrite the document each time. Use `>> output.log` to append text to a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append output to the end of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207573/how-to-append-output-to-the-end-of-a-text-file)

Comment: Regarding your quotation problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094086/passing-arguments-with-spaces-between-bash-script

Answer (score 2):

From the Curl documentation:
-I, --head Show document info only
Removing the -I or replace it with -i should solve your problem