# How do I pass a text as argument from an bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I build a little bash script where I need to pass arguments but some of those arguments will have spaces because its a sentence or something similar. I don't want to store those arguments in a file because they get changed every time.

Can anybody provide an elegant solution for this. I'm a beginner and don't know much about bash!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote your arguments such that your program receives a single argument.

Here is a simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1"
echo "$2"
```

If you invoke it like this:

```
./script.sh  'a b' 'c d'
```

The output will be:

```
a b
c d
```

Other posts that focus on this:

[Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)
[Passing arguments with spaces between (bash) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094086/passing-arguments-with-spaces-between-bash-script)

Comment: Thank you know it functions properly !

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes around the string you are passing as a variable will do the trick.

You can use environment variables by doing `export VARIABLE = "the_value"` and get the value by `$VARIABLE`

Comment: Hey I tried it and it gets recognized in the shell as one argument but not in the script.  But thanks for the fast answer I am a bit closer where I want to be !